# Managing local notifications for iOS framework with beacons

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, frameworks, beacon

I have been working on iOS framework (in Swift) which contains beacon functionality. I made it work except that I'm not sure how to handle scenario where I'm in foreground and I encounter multiple beacons in short duration.

If I want `didReceive` delegate method to show Alert for beacon while in foreground, and if I encounter many beacons it will not work nicely (alerts will display one over another). Is there some solution to queue notifications somehow?

Also I would like to know, if there is a way to make all that logic for receiving local notifications inside my framework?
I have to be able to support iOS-8.0 so I can't use Notification Center which is available from iOS-10.0

Can I create some class which would act like `appdelegate` (probably some class which would implement UIApplicationDelegate inside framework), is something like that possible?

I want to put as much code as I can inside framework itself so that it won't be too messy job for someone to include that framework with all functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I figured out a way to make this. I'm  beginner in iOS with few months experience so I can't say if this solution is the best but it works for me.

I found a way to implement all push and local notification related delegate methods from framework. Basically if main application wants framework to take care of notifications without having to implement anything yourself, on runtime framework will dynamically implement certain UIApplicationDelegate methods for AppDelegate.swift class (or whatever is your AppDelegate class called).

I used object_getClass(UIApplication.shared.delegate!) to get the main class.

Then I used  func class_addMethod(_ cls: AnyClass!, _ name: Selector!, _ imp: IMP!, _ types: UnsafePointer!) -> Bool
to implement delegate methods for push and local notifications from inside framework so now it comes down to write one or two lines to use framework entirely with working notifications and beacon location services instead of having to write a lots of code outside framework.

As for handling notifications in foreground mode I made that work by adding them to queue so that if more than one notification comes, and wants to be displayed in foreground regime, only one will be displayed by UIAlertController and the rest will be put in queue and sent again but with some small delay (I set fire date to be some value which I thought was appropriate in my case) after user makes an action  regarding that first notification which was the only one presented.

These are just my ideas for the problems I had, if someone shows interest for these solutions I will write more details if needed. I will also gladly accept any criticism.